# How to change the reference of a named range?

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

In a worksheet, I have a cell that contains the reference (in string) of a named range.
I would like this reference to replace the current reference in the named range called "LISTE_ARTICLES":

The cell that contain the reference:
[image: This image show the cell that contain the reference]

```vb
Sub Dim_Zones_Nommees()
    Dim A As String
        A = Range("REF_LISTE_ARTICLE").Value ''Chargement TC!AJ23':CK322
    Dim Col_1 As Integer
        Col_1 = Range(A).Column '36
    Dim Row_1 As Integer
        Row_1 = Range(A).Row '23
    Dim Col_2 As Integer
        Col_2 = Range(A).Cells.Columns.Count + Col_1 - 1 '89
    Dim Row_2 As Integer
        Row_2 = Range(A).Cells.Rows.Count + Row_1 - 1 '322

    With ChargtGenerique.Names.Item("LISTE_ARTICLES")
        .RefersTo = .RefersToRange.Range(Cells(Row_1, Col_1), Cells(Row_2, Col_2))
    End With
End sub
```

This return:
[image: Error Message]

Comment: In your text you write `LISTE_ARTICLE` but in your code `Item("LISTE_ARTICLES")`, is that a just a typo (then correct it) or is that the issue?

Comment: If your range `LISTE_ARTICLES` is not defined in the sheets scope but in the workbooks scope you need to use `Names.Item("LISTE_ARTICLES")` instead.

Comment: I have no problems for the first part of the code, the values shown after the quotation marks are the valuers generated by the code.
The problem is on the ".referencesto" property

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems as though you just need to read the formula from the cell named "REF_LISTE_ARTICLE" and put it directly into the "RefersTo" property, prepending an equal sign as follows

```
ChargtGenerique.Names.Item("LISTE_ARTICLES").RefersTo = "=" & Range("REF_LISTE_ARTICLE").Value
```

or, if the name is defined as the workbook level:

```
activeworkbook.Names.Item("LISTE_ARTICLES").RefersTo = "=" & Range("REF_LISTE_ARTICLE").Value
```

Comment: it doesn't work,  the reference value is wrong and i don't know why. The new value is "='Chargement TC'!BH47:DI346" but it should be "'Chargement TC!AJ23':CK322"